# concatenate two list without repeating elements

Tags: python

Given two list `A` and `B`, It the following the way to put all elements in teo set together avoiding repetitions?

```
[i for i in A \if i not in B]
```

Comment: You'll never have repetitions if you are adding them into a set. Please clarify if thats not what you want.

Comment: Do `newList = list(set(A+B))`

Comment: I'm wondering what is the use of \? I didn;t write the codes. I saw the code online.